# Design a turing machine that accepts the language L= {a^2 b^2n: n>=1}

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory, turing-machines

I want to design a turing machine that accepts the language L= {a^2b^2n: n>=1}
:. a square b square(n)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language is `a^2 b^2n = {aabb, aabbbb, aabbbbbb, ...}`, the language is regular and a TM for it first reads two `a`s, then two `b`s, then either blank or two additional `b`s at a time until a blank is found.

```
q    t    q'    t'    d
-----------------------
q0   a    q1    a     right    // read two a's from the
q1   a    q2    a     right    // beginning of the tape

q2   b    q3    b     right    // read at least two b's
q3   b    q4    b     right

q4   #    hA    #     left     // read more pairs of b's
q4   b    q3    b     right    // or halt if input is done
```

If your language is `a^2n b^2n = {aabb, aaaabbbb, aaaaaabbbbbb, ...}`, the language is context-free and a TM for it crosses off matching `aa`s and `bb`s until you run out of symbols.

```
q    t    q'    t'    d
-----------------------
q0   a    q1    #     right    // erase two a's from
q1   a    q2    #     right    // the front of the tape

q2   a    q2    a     right    // scan to the end
q2   b    q2    b     right    // of the tape
q2   #    q3    #     left

q3   b    q4    #     left     // erase two b's from
q4   b    q5    #     left     // the end of the tape

q5   a    q5    a     left     // scan to the beginning
q5   b    q5    b     left     // of the tape
q5   #    q6    #     right

q6   a    q1    a     right    // try to start erasing a's
q6   #    hA    #     -        // or halt if all input is erased
```

Comment: language is a^2 b^2n = {aabb, aabbbb, aabbbbbb, ...}. Thankyou for your answer